# MOSFET Voltage Spikes

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, powermosfet

I have a voltage source that has a square wave between 20V and 35V with 12.5khz frequency. Even i fully close the MOSFET, it is still conducting in rising and and falling edges of voltage source. How can i prevent this?

I added the LTspice schematic and analysis screenshots. The green lines are V(R1) and blue lines are V(source).

[image]

[image]

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Try connecting your FET to a constant voltage supply and connecting R2 directly to your pulse generator.

Comment: Compute R2*C where C is the FET's input capacitance, and compare with the time constant on the trailing edge of those spikes. Reducing R2 will reduce their duration.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes. The duration is reducing. But can i fully block these spikes with this square wave voltage source? Another question, are these spikes harmful when i connect V(R2) node to another circuit?

Comment: What's the purpose of this circuit? I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 2):

You are literally shortening the gate and source of your PMOS via a resistor, meaning that if you had only a DC signal as the supply voltage the MOSFET would be always OFF (open). The small signal that you see across R1, arises from the fact the MOSFET gate capacitance takes some time to charge and discharge, therefore for a very short moment, the voltage across gate-source is no longer zero, thus the MOSFET is shortly turned on.

I don't really see the purpose of your circuit. If you wanted to drive the P-FET as a switch, you would have to rearrange the AC source as follows (not sure whether that is what you want):

This circuit basically creates a voltage reference (12V) and switches the output voltage based on the AC Source.

[image: circui]

[image: waveform]

The small voltage spikes can be removed via small capacitors.